# $4$-torsion points of elliptic curve in field extension of odd degree

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over some field $k$ of characteristic not $2$. Let $m$ be the maximal number of $4$-torsion points of $E(L)$ where $L$ ranges over all finite field extensions of $k$ of odd degree. What is the best lower bound on $m$ that does not depend on $k$ and $E$?

I can at least show that one always has $m\geq 2$. Indeed, over the separable closure of $k$ we have four $2$-torsion points but one of those is the neutral element. If there was no other $2$-torsion point over $k$, then we can get (at least) one more by passing to a field extension of degree $3$.

On the other hand, there are examples when $m\leq 4$. Indeed, if $k=\mathbb{R}$ and $E(\mathbb{R})$ has only one connected component, then there are exactly four $4$-torsion points and $\mathbb{R}$ has no odd field extension.

Comment: There looks to be a little disagreement between 2-torsion and 4-torsion at a couple places in your question? You may also find division polynomials useful, or maybe not depending on how heavily you're trying to lean on the "does not depend on $k$" portion of the question.

Comment: @KReiser I don't see any disagreement:  OP is simply saying that there are always at least two $2$-torsion points over an odd-degree extension, and these are in particular also $4$-torsion points.

Comment: @RaviFernando ah, right, that makes sense. My mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lower bound $m \geq 2$ is the best possible.  In fact, I claim that if $E$ has at least one nontrivial $2$-torsion point $P$ over $k$, then all $2$-power torsion points of $E$ are defined over extensions of $k$ of $2$-power degree.  In particular, if the $2$-part of $E(k)_{\mathrm{tors}}$ is just $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ (and of course there are [many such $E$](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?hst=List&torsion=%5B2%5D&search_type=List)), then there are no additional $2$-power torsion points over any odd-degree extensions of $k$.

Proof:  fix $n \geq 1$, and choose a basis of $E[2^n] = (\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z)^2$ in which $P = (2^{n-1}, 0)$.  The mod-$2^n$ Galois representation of $E$ fixes $P$, so its image is contained in the subgroup
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 + 2\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z & * \\ 2\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z & 1 + 2\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z \end{pmatrix} \subset \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/2^n \mathbb Z).
$$
But this subgroup has $2$-power order--namely order $2^{4n-3}$.  Therefore its kernel is $G_L < G_k$, where $L$ is a $2$-power extension of $k$.  This $L$ is the smallest field over which all $2^n$-torsion points of $E$ are defined.